# Ubuntu 20.04 filesystem checks with every boot

Tags: boot, grub2, filesystem

I have a dual boot (Windows 10 on an SSD and Ubuntu 20.04 on an HDD) and I am using an Acer laptop.

I have had this problem of filesystem check for a couple of months now, Ubuntu does a filesystem check at boot every time I boot the machine! I tried some of the fixes I found such as fsck.mode=skip but that command does not exist on my system!

note: I am relatively new to Linux, If I need to attach more info please tell me, and thanks to anyone willing to help.

Answer to comment: I have no idea the cause of filesystem check, It does not return any information, also, I shut my computer using the shutdown button but I have noticed that after restarting, Chrome thinks it had improper shutdown and offers to restore tabs!

Comment: Rather than just suppress the fsck, you should find out what is triggering the check.  Improper shutdown is the most likely cause, Could be a failing disk too. Do you get any errors when running the fsck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add `fsck.mode=skip` in the file `/etc/default/grub` in line with the parameter **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT** :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash fsck.mode=skip"
```

Then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: this worked, thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: Very bad idea. Full system check is triggered because the file system is unclean. You should rather find out what is causing this check. After every reboot into Ubuntu? After having booted in Windows? You will find yourself with an unbootable system sooner or later if an unclean file system is not checked.

Comment: how can I find out the cause of this filesystem check? btw I had triple boot with Ubuntu 16 and it did not trigger filesystem checks! only Ubuntu 20.04